# counter multiple choice quiz using radiobuttons

Tags: vb.net, radio-button, counter

I'm having an issue with my score counter not counting, when the msgbox pops up, it doesn't display the score received, just "0". I have looked at various other questions telling the answer of how to use the program counter but their solutions don't seem to work for me.

```
Dim grade1, percentage1 As String
Dim score1 As Integer
```

^^ the declorations

```
 score1 = "0"
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 1
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 0
    End If
    If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 1
    ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 0
    End If
    If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 1
    ElseIf RadioButton6.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 0
    End If
    If RadioButton8.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 1
    ElseIf RadioButton7.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 0
    End If
    If RadioButton9.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 1
    ElseIf RadioButton10.Checked = True Then
        score1 = score1 + 0
    End If
    Select Case score1
        Case 1
            score1 = 0
            grade1 = "U" & percentage1 = "0%"
        Case 2
            score1 = 1
            grade1 = "D" & percentage1 = "20%"
        Case 3
            score1 = 2
            grade1 = "C" & percentage1 = "40%"
        Case 4
            score1 = 3
            grade1 = "B" & percentage1 = "60%"
        Case 5
            score1 = 4
            grade1 = "A" & percentage1 = "80%"
        Case 6
            score1 = 5
            grade1 = "A*" & percentage1 = "100%"

    End Select

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox("Your score is" + score1.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    MsgBox("Your grade is" + grade1, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    MsgBox("Your percentage is" + percentage1, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should add `Option Strict On` to the top of your file. `"0"` is not an integer.  Then set a breakpoint and debug your code.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour] ; the system is probably getting close to limiting how often you can post

Comment: What event is running that code?  Use the debugger.  `score1 = score1 + 0` Huh?

Comment: Simple advices: avoid things like `score1 = score1 + 0`. It only makes your code longer. `score1 = score1 + 1` can be written `score1 += 1`, this is shorter and a better way to do in many languages. `If RadioButton8.Checked = True Then` should be written `If RadioButton8.Checked Then`, that is the meaning of a boolean. Last but not least, when you manipulate similar dataset, try to use Lists or Dictionaries instead of many `if - then` and `select` statements.

Comment: I think that the sub that computes the score is never called. Call it just before the MsgBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I hope this question is still active?)
I suppose based on your question, that you are still a beginner in programming.
Bob gave some useful tips and now i try to answer your question.
There are several things, that you need to change and some other improvements.

**First:**

`score1 = "0"` should be `score1 = 0`.
You declared score1 as integer, but with the quotation marks you try to set its value to a string. Like Plutonix mentioned.

**Second:**

You want to make a little multiple choice quiz game and use radio buttons. From what i know radio buttons were created to force only one choice.
If you check one radiobutton all other radio buttons will uncheck.
The control you should go for are checkboxes.
Hint: Be aware, that the user could check both checkboxes. If one is checked you should disable the other until the first box is unchecked.

**Third:**

You asked, what you should write instead of `score1 = score1+0`.
The answer: Nothing. If you write no code in the condition nothing will happen and the score will not change.

E.g. ->

```
If CheckBox9.Checked = True Then
            score1 = score1 + 1
        ElseIf RadioButton10.Checked = True Then
        End If
```

But you can improve this code more. CheckBox.Checked is a function, which returns a boolean (true/false). You can shorten the code of the if condition like this:

```
If CheckBox9.Checked Then
        score1 +=1
```

**Fourth:**

```
grade1 = "U" & percentage1 = "0%"
```

If you want to set two variables to two different values do it in two lines.

```
grade1 = "U"
percentage1 = "0%"
```

Besides this, you don't need the `score1 = ...` in the select case.
Select case is looking up the value of the given variable score1 and selects the case, where score1 equals the cases expression.
For example, if the user checked all boxes with the right answers, the select case will do the code at case 5, because score1 = 5.

Select Case info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement

**Last but not least:**

You should write the logic of the checkboxes into an sub:

```
Private Sub CalculateScore()

    If CheckBox1.Checked  Then
        score1 = score1 + 1

'Here comes the code for the other checkboxes and the select case...
End Sub
```

This sub should be called within your Button1_Click event, before the MsgBoxes are called. Like Bob mentioned.

I hope with this post most of your questiones are answered.
If i was to inaccurate or you don't understand something feel free to ask.

Best Regards

SgtMeowBlank